# jsonp proxy web app I can install?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsonp

After getting stuck [trying to access another domain with ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150208/javascript-want-to-access-the-contents-of-another-domain-with-ajax) I discovered I'll need to use jsonp. However the web service I'm using doesn't provide jsonp output. No problem, I can write something simple on my own webserver that will wrap the output of their thing with jsonp. However before I reinvent the wheel, is there some exisiting programme that will do this for me?

Answer (score 2):

Try YQL: **http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/**

Also, see this: "**[How to use YQL to retrieve web results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176668/how-to-use-yql-to-retrieve-web-results)**"